# How Do I find the positions of a vector in R comparing with other vector

Tags: r

I know it seems trivial but suppose I have a vector v such that:

```
v <- 20:50
```

and a vector s, such that:

```
s <- c(30, 36, 37, 58)
```

Is there a way to compare the two vector such that we get the positions of the values of 'v' which are equal to the values of 's'? It would be a generalization of:

```
v[v==30]
```

but with all values of s. Some like:

```
 v[v==s]
```

Comment: `which(v %in% s)` maybe?

Comment: `match()` will include NA (or chosen `nomatch` value) but is still a good choice

Comment: I was just adding that to my comment when yours popped up. Yes, depends on how you want to handle non-matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want something like this to get the positions of `v` that are in `s`.

```
which(v %in% s)
# [1] 11 17 18
```

If the values are always unique, you can create a named vector showing the value matches.

```
setNames(which(v %in% s), s[s %in% v])
# 30 36 37 
# 11 17 18
```

Answer (score 0):

`unlist(sapply(s, function(x) v[v==x]))`

Result:

```
> v <- 20:50
> s <- c(30, 36, 37, 58)
> unlist(sapply(s, function(x) v[v==x]))
[1] 30 36 37
```

Comment: Strangely, this returns a list even though you've use `sapply`, so you need to wrap it in `unlist()` to get a vector of positions.

Comment: That is weird. A bug, maybe? Documentation seems to suggest it should return a vector. Anyway, I edited my answer.